# Typescript get properties of Parent interface from Child interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, types, interface

very simple question.. yet I dont know. I have following example from code

```js
interface A {
    a:string;
}

interface B extends A{
    b:string;
}

const b:B = {
    a:'a',
    b:'b'
}

const a:A = b;

console.log(a)
```

The question is. Now it prints both properties 'a' and 'b'. However I would only like to get the A properties excluding the B properties.

Any anser appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a minor confusion between original purpose of TypeScript and the core of JavaScript. For example, when we mutate or create clones of JavaScript Objects, there is no room for TS by default.

In your question, you're **creating a reference** to existing object instead of cloning a new one. That seems to be a core problem.

This is my approach to the actual given problem (see [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBt3IN4ChkHJwBcyAzmFKAOYDc+hARqRVSHbgL665gCeABxQB5EOj6pkAXmQAFYAgDWAHgzoANMgDkcLQD56uBAHsQFZMMYArCAjBrSa6TmQAiOK9LvXm1409u-sichiZmYC4kFta29sGkouKSMpY2dmqGRqZkxugQAHToxtQAFFqpsWpamhXpmACU9GE5eYXFZbX21dFp9o24QA) for details). But check this, if it helps in your case.

```js
interface All {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type OnlyA = Pick<All, 'a'>;

const ObjectAll: All = { "a": "a", "b": "b" };
const { a: ObjectA }: OnlyA = ObjectAll;

console.log('ObjectAll', ObjectAll);
console.log('ObjectA', ObjectA);
```